# gcc makefile with -Wall -pedantic and -lpthread

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gcc-pedantic

I have tried to make a makefile from a template and this is what I've got:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
LFLAGS = -lpthread
CC = gcc
OBJS = bank5.o client2.o
PROGRAM = ex2

all: bank client

ex2: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM)

bank: bank5.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bank5.c receive_message.c send_message.c -o bank5

client: client2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c client2.c receive_message.c send_message.c -o client2
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -c bank5.c receive_message.c send_message.c -o bank5
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [bank] Error 4
```

This is what my makefile looked like before -Wall and -pedantic, this ran normally:

```
all: bank client

bank: bank5.c
    gcc bank5.c receive_message.c send_message.c -o bank5 -lpthread

client: client2.c
    gcc -o client2 client2.c send_message.c receive_message.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-c` will just compile each file (i.e., produce an object file), not link them together. Because one object file corresponds to one source file, **multiple object files will be created**.
- `-o` specifies **one** output file.

Obviously, both contradict each other.

Remove the `-c` to fix the problem.

---

Anyway, your makefile looks broken. What does `ex2` do there? `bank5.o` and `client2.o` are nowhere created.

Comment: Like I said, I was doing it from a template and the template had those.